# dropdown list with autocomplete/ suggestion in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

In a merged cell (named as SelName) I have a dropdown list with more then 100 items. Searching through the list is not efficient, as this list is constantly growing. Therefore, I would like to have a dropdown list with autocomplete/ suggestion function. One of the codes that I have is the following which I have found on extendoffice.com:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
'Update by Extendoffice: 2017/8/15
Dim xCombox As OLEObject
Dim xStr As String
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim Cancel As Boolean
Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet

'On Error Resume Next
Set xCombox = xWs.OLEObjects("TempCombo")
With xCombox
    .ListFillRange = ""
    .LinkedCell = ""
    .Visible = False
End With
If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
    Target.Validation.InCellDropdown = False
    Cancel = True
    xStr = Target.Validation.Formula1
    xStr = Right(xStr, Len(xStr) - 1)
    If xStr = "" Then Exit Sub
    With xCombox
        .Visible = True
        .Left = Target.Left
        .Top = Target.Top
        .Width = Target.Width + 5
        .Height = Target.Height + 5
        .ListFillRange = xStr
        .LinkedCell = Target.Address
    End With
    xCombox.Activate
    Me.TempCombo.DropDown
End If
End Sub

 Private Sub TempCombo_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
Select Case KeyCode
    Case 9
        Application.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    Case 13
        Application.ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
End Select
End Sub
```

First, I tried to test it in an empty sheet (with just the dropdown list) and it worked well. But as soon as I try to insert this code into the other worksheet, it doesn't. Does anyone has an idea what the problem could be?
FYI: I have several drop down lists in this worksheet and all of them are in merged cells. Additionally, I have some other Private subs...

Comment: *"Doesn't work"* is no description of an issue, it's meaningless. Please tell which error you get and where. Or what happens instead of what you expect to happen. Also check the name of your combo box `TempCombo`? • Also remove `On Error Resume Next` this line hides all error messages. You cannot fix errors that you don't see.

Comment: I would expect that when I enter the first few letters that all the items starting with these letters would appear in the list (like google search results). In my case, the dropdown list doesn't list any item. I get the error "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: In which line do you get the error?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ for line If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then

Comment: OK, obviously you need that `On Error Resume Next` even if this is a bad practice to do so. Also you obviously must use the [Data Validation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249) and set it to "List" to make that drop down list work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you have to do that instead of just creating a ComboBox control and setting `ListFillRange` and `LinkedCell` without any code?

The error happens because the Range you are editing (`Target`) does not have any Validation. You should add the check for validation:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim vType As XlDVType
    On Error GoTo EndLine
    vType = Target.Validation.Type

    Dim xCombox As OLEObject
    Dim xStr As String
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim Cancel As Boolean
    Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet

    'On Error Resume Next
    Set xCombox = xWs.OLEObjects("TempCombo")
    With xCombox
        .ListFillRange = ""
        .LinkedCell = ""
        .Visible = False
    End With
    If vType = 3 Then
        Target.Validation.InCellDropdown = False
        Cancel = True
        xStr = Target.Validation.Formula1
        xStr = Right(xStr, Len(xStr) - 1)
        If xStr = "" Then Exit Sub
        With xCombox
            .Visible = True
            .Left = Target.Left
            .Top = Target.Top
            .Width = Target.Width + 5
            .Height = Target.Height + 5
            .ListFillRange = xStr
            .LinkedCell = Target.Address
        End With
        xCombox.Activate
        Me.TempCombo.DropDown
    End If
EndLine:
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

If i understand the problem correctly, you want a ComboBox that auto-fills from a column and auto-updates if you type more entries in the column. There is no need for such complicated code. You can simply add a ComboBox (say ComboBox1), set its ListFillRange (e.g. to `A1:A20`) and do this:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
        With ComboBox1
            Dim OrigRange As Range: OrigRange = .ListFillRange
            If Not Application.Intersect(OrigRange, Target) Is Nothing Then
                .ListFillRange = .OrigRange.Resize(OrigRange.Cells(1).End(xlDown).Row - OrigRange.Row + 1)
            End If
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: your code works well, if I define my range as =Sheet1!A2:A10. Whereas, =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2;0;0;COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1) doesn't display any of the items. Is there reason for it? Do other Private Subs have an impact? For instance, I have a Private Sub in order to have multiple selection dropdown list.

Comment: You mean `ListFillRange`? You can't define a Range with a formula. In VBA `Range("OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2;0;0;COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1)")` will give you an error.

Comment: @iammanigeeit, in Data Validation -> source I have entered =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2;0;0;COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1) to get a dropdown list which automatically will be updated when a new value is added. For these cells, the code doesn't work. If I set the source for the dropdown list as Sheet1!A2:A10, there's absolutely no problem...

Comment: `;` doesn't work for me.. formulas should use `,` as the separator

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete Dropdowns are now native with excel O365
https://www.excel-university.com/autocomplete-for-data-validation-dropdown-lists/