# VBA Excel dropdown list autocomplete - problem with list autoupdate

Tags: excel, vba, list, combobox

Good afternoon,

I would like to have my list auto-update working, but I don't know how to do it.

[image]

The list, which you can see above is my test list. There is combobox on the right, in which properties I set:
Linkked column as R2
Cell range as: A2:A6.

It works fine, what you can see on your right dropdown. The records from cell range A2:A6 are properly populated.

The problem is, that this list is going to be developed, as the new data will come up row by row. In this event I can't keep this range fixed.

I tried to manage it with the code provided here:

[dropdown list with autocomplete/ suggestion in excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52217526/dropdown-list-with-autocomplete-suggestion-in-excel-vba)

and so far my code looks as follows:

```
 Option Explicit

 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim vType As XlDVType
  On Error GoTo EndLine
  vType = Target.Validation.Type

 Dim xCombox As OLEObject
 Dim xStr As String
 Dim xWs As Worksheet
 Dim Cancel As Boolean
 Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet

  'On Error Resume Next
  Set xCombox = xWs.OLEObjects("Combobox1")
  With xCombox
   Dim OrigRange As Range: OrigRange = .ListFillRange
     If Not Application.Intersect(OrigRange, Target) Is Nothing Then
            .ListFillRange = .OrigRange.Resize(OrigRange.Cells(1).End(xlDown).Row - OrigRange.Row + 1)
    End If
    '.ListFillRange = .OrigRange.Resize(OrigRange.Cells(1).End(xlDown).Row - OrigRange.Row + 1)
    .LinkedCell = "=A"
    .Visible = False
   End With
   If vType = 3 Then
    Target.Validation.InCellDropdown = False
    Cancel = True
    xStr = Target.Validation.Formula1
    xStr = Right(xStr, Len(xStr) - 1)
    If xStr = "" Then Exit Sub
    With xCombox
        .Visible = True
        .Left = Target.Left
        .Top = Target.Top
        .Width = Target.Width + 5
        .Height = Target.Height + 5
        .ListFillRange = xStr
        .LinkedCell = Target.Address
    End With
    xCombox.Activate
    Me.ComboBox1.DropDown
   End If
  EndLine:
 End Sub
```

The code works with autofill, it's good. However I had to mix something, because I see no reaction now. The code works and autofill is correct as it was, but the auto-update doesn't work. I put the new values underneath, beyond the fixed cell range in the properties and they don't appear in the dropdown, what you can see.

Is there any way to make it running?

UPDATE:

The most recent approaching to the problem:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim vType As XlDVType
On Error GoTo EndLine
vType = Target.Validation.Type

Dim xCombox As OLEObject
Dim xStr As String
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim Cancel As Boolean
Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet

'On Error Resume Next
Set xCombox = xWs.OLEObjects("Combobox1")
With xCombox
Dim OrigRange As Range: Set OrigRange = xWs.Range("A2:A" & xWs.Range("A" & xWs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
If Not Application.Intersect(OrigRange, Target) Is Nothing Then
.ListFillRange = OrigRange.Address
End If
.LinkedCell = "R2" '??
.Visible = True 'Dont know why hide ??
 End With
If vType = 3 Then
    Target.Validation.InCellDropdown = False
    Cancel = True
    xStr = Target.Validation.Formula1
    xStr = Right(xStr, Len(xStr) - 1)
    If xStr = "" Then Exit Sub
    With xCombox
        .Visible = True
        .Left = Target.Left
        .Top = Target.Top
        .Width = Target.Width + 5
        .Height = Target.Height + 5
        .ListFillRange = xStr
        .LinkedCell = Target.Address
    End With
    xCombox.Activate
    Me.ComboBox1.DropDown
 End If
 EndLine:
End Sub
```

After removing the ListFillRange property the combobox dropdown list is completely blank.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: Nothing wrong with the validation part of the code as it is a list validation with formula, its hard to imagine.

ComboBox ListFillRange property is a string.

So

```
Dim OrigRange As Range: OrigRange = .ListFillRange
xCombox.ListFillRange = .OrigRange.Resize(OrigRange.Cells(1).End(xlDown).Row - OrigRange.Row + 1)
```

will not work

```
Dim OrigRange As Range: Set OrigRange = Range(.ListFillRange)
xCombox.ListFillRange = .OrigRange.Resize(OrigRange.Cells(1).End(xlDown).Row - OrigRange.Row + 1).Address
```

will work

But since `OrigRange` is set before the Intersect condition, the `Target` Range will always fall outside the `OrigRange` which is `=Range(.ListFillRange)` and hence `ListFillRange` will never update. Replacing the `With xCombox` block with the following will help. Try:

```
With xCombox
Dim OrigRange As Range: Set OrigRange = xWs.Range("A2:A" & xWs.Range("A" & xWs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    If Not Application.Intersect(OrigRange, Target) Is Nothing Then
    .ListFillRange = OrigRange.Address
    End If
.LinkedCell = "=A" '??
.Visible = False 'Dont know why hide ??
End With
```

I wonder if the Target values are limited by a list then you could use the same list for the combobox.

**Edit**
Try his code first. Everything related to validation is removed. If this works you can think about validation, though I wonder why validation!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim xCombox As OLEObject
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
Dim OrigRange As Range
Set OrigRange = xWs.Range("A2:A" & xWs.Range("A" & xWs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Set xCombox = xWs.OLEObjects("Combobox1")
With xCombox
If Not Application.Intersect(OrigRange, Target) Is Nothing Then
.ListFillRange = OrigRange.Address
End If
    .LinkedCell = "R2" '??
    .Visible = True 'Dont know why hide ??
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.

I switch on the editor mode for my combobox and tried to change the ListFillRange from A2:A, but it was gone every time, as the "A2:A" statement was wrong. When is nothing in "ListFillRange" then I can't select any order. See my code updated on your basis. Are you able to tell me where am I wrong?

Comment: You don't have to change ListFillRange  in the Combobox properties. This procedure will take care of it.. Also, `Dim OrigRange As Range: Set OrigRange = xWs.Range("A2:A" & xWs.Range("A" & 
xWs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)` has to be on the same line. It appears on two rows in your new code.

Comment: I fixed the code, but it didn't help either. I have the blank combobox, as you can see in the image.
Another query is:
Shall I run this code from the Sheet1 or input it whole in the Combobox1 code?

Comment: It is a worksheet event so you have to run the code from the worksheet in which the combobox is

Comment: OK I did it, but it doesn't work. Could you skip through my code and see what can be wrong or missed?

Comment: I would suggest remove everything related to the validation and just try to populate the combobox first. `On Error GoTo EndLine`  causes to hide the error. Remove that. Do not use error handler then you will know where the error is

Comment: I removed, butt in this event I have only one record and the debugger says:
Application-defined or object-defined error pointing the:
Type = Taget.Validation.Type

Comment: stil the same. Remember, that i want to keep the autofill option too. If this code doesn't work, maybe have you got another code or link to some solutions, which might be helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214407/discussion-between-naresh-bhople-and-mariusz-krukar).