Excel Table Autofill Validation via vba code
I have a table with several columns, but three of them need validation where if someone starts typing the first letter of an item in the list that it automatically fills the rest.  Example column A: type Un fills in Unit.  I have the validation working the old way where there is a drop down list that then has to be manually selected.  I don't want to use my mouse to run a small scroll bar to select what I can type faster.  However, I need the validation so that the many users who will be using this table enter the value that I need in the field.  The code below is running but not finding based on the first few letters that is typed.  Any suggestions on how to get this work?
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 'Application.EnableEvents = False
    'If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
     'Call Validation Column A
     Call setTypeValidation(Target.Row)
    End If
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(2)) Is Nothing Then
        ' Call Validation for column B
        Call setGroupValidation(Target.Row)
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(7)) Is Nothing Then
        ' Call Validation for column G
        Call setStateValidation(Target.Row)
    End If

    'Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub
  Sub setTypeValidation(idxRow As Long)
    ' column A
    With Cells(idxRow, 1).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="New, Unit, Used"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = "Only New, Unit, Used allowed."
        .IMEMode = xlIMEModeNoControl
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
   End Sub
   Sub setGroupValidation(idxRow As Long)
    ' column B
    With Cells(idxRow, 2).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="1, 2, 3, 4, 5UR, 7, 08, 09, 10AA, 9999"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = "Only valid Group allowed."
        .IMEMode = xlIMEModeNoControl
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    End Sub
    Sub setStateValidation(idxRow As Long)
    ' Column G
    With Cells(idxRow, 7).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="AK-Alaska, AL-Alabama, AR-Arkansas, AZ-Arizona, CA-California, CO- Colorado, CT-Connecticut, DC-District of Columbia, DE-Delaware, FL-Florida, IN-Indiana, KY-Kentucky, IA-Iowa, KS-Kansas, GA-Georgia, LA-Louisiana, ID-Idaho, HI-Hawaii, IL-Illinois, MA-Massachusetts, MD-Maryland, ME-Maine, MI-Michigan, MN-Minnesota, MO-Missouri, MS-Mississippi, MT-Montana, NC-North Carolina, ND-North Dakota, NE-Nebraska, NH-New Hampshire, NJ-New Jersey, NM-New Mexico, NV-Nevada, NY-New York, OH-Ohio, OK-Oklahoma, OR-Oregon, PA-Pennsylvania, RI-Rhode Island, SC-South Carolina, SD-South Dakota, TN-Tennessee, TX-Texas, UT-Utah, VA-Virginia, VT-Vermont, WA-Washington, WI-Wisconsin, WV-West Virginia, WY-Wyoming"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = "Only State drop down format allowed."
        .IMEMode = xlIMEModeNoControl
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub

The table that I have could have well over 100 records at a time that need to be validated.  I need this to work for each tab through to the next field.  Any ideas would be of assistance.  Thanks so much.

Do you have this feature in your Excel version?  https://www.excel-university.com/autocomplete-for-data-validation-dropdown-lists/    If not, there are other approaches such as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52217526/dropdown-list-with-autocomplete-suggestion-in-excel-vba

BTW did you mean to use the SelectionChange event and not the Change event?

FYI your "states" validation list is too long - it will not error when applying the list, but if the file is saved and re-opened the user will get an error message about removed content...

I've created a broadly appliable solution. To demonstrate it, let's assume we have this situation:



Status
ID
State

Status
ID
State








New
1
AK-Alaska






Unit
2
AL-Alabama






Used
3
AR-Arkansas







4
AZ-Arizona







5UR
CA-California







7
CO-Colorado







'08
CT-Connecticut







'09
DC-District of Columbia







10AA
DE-Delaware







9999
FL-Florida








IN-Indiana








KY-Kentucky








IA-Iowa








KS-Kansas








GA-Georgia








LA-Louisiana








ID-Idaho








HI-Hawaii








IL-Illinois








MA-Massachusetts








MD-Maryland








ME-Maine








MI-Michigan








MN-Minnesota








MO-Missouri








MS-Mississippi








MT-Montana








NC-North Carolina








ND-North Dakota








NE-Nebraska








NH-New Hampshire








NJ-New Jersey








NM-New Mexico








NV-Nevada








NY-New York








OH-Ohio








OK-Oklahoma








OR-Oregon








PA-Pennsylvania








RI-Rhode Island








SC-South Carolina








SD-South Dakota








TN-Tennessee








TX-Texas








UT-Utah








VA-Virginia








VT-Vermont








WA-Washington








WI-Wisconsin








WV-West Virginia








WY-Wyoming



Where columns A, B and C are for the inputs while columns E, F and G are for the database of possible inputs. Now we can use put this code in the sheet module:
Option Explicit

Private Sub CmbActivateList_Click()
    
    Dim ObjList As Object
    Dim StrListName As String
    
    StrListName = "LblList"
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ObjList = Me.Shapes(StrListName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Select Case Me.CmbActivateList.Caption
        Case Is = "Lists: ON"
            
            Me.CmbActivateList.Caption = "Lists: OFF"
            
            If ObjList Is Nothing Then
                
            Else
                ObjList.Visible = False
            End If
            
        Case Is = "Lists: OFF"
            
            Me.CmbActivateList.Caption = "Lists: ON"
            
            Call Worksheet_SelectionChange(Selection)
            
        Case Else
            
            Me.CmbActivateList.Caption = "Lists: OFF"
            
    End Select
    
End Sub

Private Sub LblList_Click()
    
    Dim ObjButton As Object
    Dim StrButtonName As String
    Dim RngButtonLocation As Range
    
    StrButtonName = "CmbActivateList"
    Set RngButtonLocation = Me.Range("I1")
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ObjButton = Me.Shapes(StrButtonName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If ObjButton Is Nothing Then
        
        Set ObjButton = Me.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", _
                                                 Link:=False, _
                                                 DisplayAsIcon:=False _
                                                 )
        ObjButton.Name = StrButtonName
        
        ObjButton.Object.Caption = "Lists: OFF"
        
        ObjButton.Object.AutoSize = True
        
        ObjButton.Object.AutoSize = False
        
        ObjButton.Object.TakeFocusOnClick = False
        
        Set ObjButton = Me.Shapes(StrButtonName)
        
    Else
        
        ObjButton.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Caption = "Lists: OFF"
        
    End If
    
    ObjButton.Left = RngButtonLocation.Left
    ObjButton.Top = RngButtonLocation.Top
    
    Me.LblList.Visible = False
    
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim ObjList As Object
    Dim StrValue As String
    Dim StrList As String
    Dim StrListName As String
    Dim StrMarker As String
    Dim RngFocus As Range
    Dim StrError As String
    
    StrListName = "LblList"
    StrMarker = " | "
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ObjList = Me.Shapes(StrListName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If ObjList Is Nothing Then
        
    Else
        
        StrList = ObjList.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Caption
        StrError = "Insert an integer between 1 and " & UBound(Split(StrList, StrMarker))
        
        If Intersect(Target, Selection) Is Nothing Then
            
            Set RngFocus = Target
            
        Else
            
            Set RngFocus = Selection
            
        End If
        
        
        If ObjList.Visible = True Then
            
            If IsNumeric(Target.Value2) Then
                
                If Round(Target.Value2, 0) = Target.Value2 Then
                    
                    If Target.Value2 > 0 And Target.Value2 <= UBound(Split(StrList, StrMarker)) Then
                        
                        If Target.Cells(1, 1).Value2 = "" Then
                            
                            RngFocus.ClearContents
                            
                        Else
                            
                            RngFocus.Value2 = Split(Split(StrList, StrMarker)(Target.Value2), vbCrLf)(0)
                            
                        End If
                        
                        StrError = ""
                        
                    End If
                    
                End If
                
            End If
            
            If Target.Cells(1, 1).Value2 = "" Then
                
                RngFocus.ClearContents
                
                StrError = ""
                
            Else
                
                If UBound(Split(StrList, StrMarker & Target.Value2 & vbCrLf)) > 0 Or Right(StrList, Len(StrMarker & Target.Value2)) = StrMarker & Target.Value2 Then
                    
                    StrError = ""
                    
                    RngFocus.Value2 = Target.Value2
                    
                End If
                
            End If
            
            If StrError = "" Then
                
            Else
                
                RngFocus.Activate
                
                Target.Value2 = ""
                
                MsgBox StrError, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Invalid input"
                
            End If
            
        End If
        
    End If
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim VarRanges() As Variant
    Dim RngData As Range
    Dim ObjList As Object
    Dim RngList As Range
    Dim StrListName As String
    Dim StrList As String
    Dim StrMarker As String
    Dim RngFocus As Range
    Dim RngRange01 As Range
    Dim DblIndex As Double
    Dim ObjButton As Object
    Dim StrButtonName As String
    
    StrButtonName = "CmbActivateList"
    StrListName = "LblList"
    StrMarker = " | "
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ObjList = Me.Shapes(StrListName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ReDim VarRanges(1 To 3, 1 To 2) As Variant
    
    VarRanges(1, 1) = "A2:A" & Rows.Count
    VarRanges(1, 2) = "E2"
    VarRanges(2, 1) = "B2:B" & Rows.Count
    VarRanges(2, 2) = "F2"
    VarRanges(3, 1) = "C2:C" & Rows.Count
    VarRanges(3, 2) = "G2"
    
    For DblIndex = LBound(VarRanges, 1) To UBound(VarRanges, 1)
        
        Set RngRange01 = Range(VarRanges(DblIndex, 2))
        
        If RngRange01.Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
            
            Set RngRange01 = Range(RngRange01, RngRange01.End(xlDown))
            
            VarRanges(DblIndex, 2) = RngRange01.Address
             
        End If
        
        
        If RngData Is Nothing Then
            
            Set RngData = Intersect(Target, Range(VarRanges(DblIndex, 1)))
            
            Set RngList = Range(VarRanges(DblIndex, 2))
            
        Else
            
            Set RngRange01 = Intersect(Target, Range(VarRanges(DblIndex, 1)))
            
            If RngRange01 Is Nothing Then
                
            Else
                
                If RngRange01.Cells.Count > RngData.Cells.Count Then
                    
                    Set RngData = RngRange01
                    
                    Set RngList = Range(VarRanges(DblIndex, 2))
                    
                End If
                
            End If
            
        End If
        
    Next
    
    
    
    
    If RngData Is Nothing Then
        
        If ObjList Is Nothing Then
            
        Else
            
            ObjList.Visible = False
            ObjList.Top = 0
            ObjList.Left = 0
            
        End If
        
    Else
        
        
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ObjButton = Me.Shapes(StrButtonName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If ObjButton Is Nothing Then
            
        Else
            
            Select Case ObjButton.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Caption
                Case Is = "Lists: OFF"
                    
                    GoTo CP_Show_Lists_END
                    
                Case Is = "Lists: ON"
                    
                Case Else
                    
                    ObjButton.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Caption = "Lists: ON"
                    
            End Select
            
        End If
        
        
        
        Intersect(Target, RngData).Select
        
        Set RngFocus = Selection.Cells(1, 1)
        
        
        If ObjList Is Nothing Then
            
            Set ObjList = Me.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Label.1", _
                                            Link:=False, _
                                            DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
                                            Left:=RngFocus.Left + RngFocus.Width + 3, _
                                            Top:=RngFocus.Top, _
                                            Width:=100, _
                                            Height:=100 _
                                           )
            
            
            
            ObjList.Name = StrListName
            
            With ObjList.Object
                
                .BorderStyle = 1
                .BackColor = RGB(160, 225, 120)
                
            End With
            
            Set ObjList = Me.Shapes(StrListName)
            
        Else
            
            ObjList.Visible = True
            ObjList.Top = RngFocus.Top
            ObjList.Left = RngFocus.Left + RngFocus.Width + 3
            
        End If
        
        
        
        DblIndex = 1
        
        For Each RngRange01 In RngList
            
            StrList = StrList & DblIndex & StrMarker & RngRange01.Value2 & vbCrLf
            
            DblIndex = DblIndex + 1
            
        Next
        
        StrList = Left(StrList, Len(StrList) - 1)
        
        
        With ObjList.OLEFormat.Object.Object
            .Caption = StrList
            .AutoSize = True
            .WordWrap = False
        
        End With
        
        
        
        With ActiveWindow.VisibleRange
            Select Case True
                Case Is = .Height < ObjList.Height
                    ObjList.Top = .Top
                Case Is = Range(RngFocus, ActiveWindow.VisibleRange(.Rows.Count, 1)).Height < ObjList.Height
                    
                    Set RngRange01 = ActiveWindow.VisibleRange(.Rows.Count, 1)
                    
                    ObjList.Top = RngRange01.Top + RngRange01.Height - ObjList.Height
                    
                Case Else
                
            End Select
        End With
        
    End If
    
CP_Show_Lists_END:
    
End Sub

Now to test it we can just select any cells in the columns A, B or C (headers excluded) and the code will make appear a list of possible inputs. The user can choose between them by specifing their index. For example: in column A (options' list in column E) we will insert 1 to obtain "New" or 3 to obtain "Used". The code will force the user to select cells belonging to the given column of interest. If more than one column of interest is selected, the code will pick the one with more cells selected. If the numbers of cells selected in said columns are equal, the code will pick the one with the lower index as specified in the VarRanges. If the list is too long to fit between a active cell (just selected) and the end of the visible range, the list will be placed with its bottom at the bottom of the visible range. If the visible range is not high enouth for the list, the list will be placed with the same top of the visible range. If the user try to insert an invalid index, the code will prevent it. If the user use the excel basic autofill (therefore to insert a name that is already in the list), the code will allow it. To prevent the list from showing up (warning: this will also let the user to insert invalid input), just click on it or click on the dedicated button; click again on said button to allow the list to show up.
Anyway a dedicated userform will much likely be more elegant (at least in the case of long lists). I'd suggest a textbox for the user to specify the searchword and a listbox to show the results.
